# Godaddy domain and Bluehost web hosting

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, web-hosting, server-settings

I have a domain from Godaddy and web hosting at Bluehost. I want to make this work as some people say no need to transfer the domain from Godaddy to Bluehost. I was trying to find out how to get this work out by adding name servers for Bluehost `ns1.bluehost.com ns2.bluehost.com` at Godaddy. This works fine, but not sure if 100% OK yet. The reason why I say that is when I type in my address name on any browser this way: **mydomain.com** it doesn't work. Instead I get an error message stating that this server is not found or couldn't connect to it...

However, when I write the domain name and include the **www.** prefix it works fine...

The other problem is when I search in google or yahoo, the domain shows like this: **mydomain.com** , which is not really good because my clients think my site is down because of the error message, and most new people don't know if they have to add **www.** to the domain to work.

I just want to make at least the domain works like this: mydomain.com

Comment: Does the output of `host mydomain.com` resolve to the correct IP address?

Comment: I had to flush the DNS as well as what **devnull** said to make work. Now it is all fine. Thanks for all for the great assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On godaddy Domain manager select DNS manager
there you should should have under "A"
Host    Points to
@

in points to you need to put the IP address (NOT ns1.bluehost.com )which for ns1.bluehost.com would be 74.220.195.31

so the result would be something like

Host      Points to 
@ ......  IP address (e.g. 74.220.195.31)

NOTE that you would need to put the IP of your website / blue host account in case that their ns1. or ns2. address doesn't work but it should

Comment: glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `A` record for `mydomain.com` pointing to the IP address of your Bluehost account.

Comment: Thanks ErikA, can you explain a little more... I mean do I have to add A record at Godaddy?

Comment: If I type in on the address bar my dedicated IP address it works, but not when I type in mydomain.com

Comment: You need to add the A record wherever your DNS is hosted, which is Bluehost.

Comment: Thanks. I already did that, but still not working...